# jQuery on Change Event Of Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to bind an event to input field. The event should fire when the value of input has been changed ( does not matter how it's changed ).

The input element is being appended first, for which I think it's not applying the event.

That is the function that adds the element into the table, now I need to check the value of input field, if input field changes anytime I have to change the total price inside the table.

The next issue comes when I try to check if Item is already added to the table, if the item is in the table, then I should increase its value of input field, if it's a new item then it should populate the table with data.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

    // Document is ready.

    var data = {};

    console.log('log');

    $('.tile').bind('click', addOrder);

    $(document).on('change', '.quantitiy', inputTotal);

});

function inputTotal() {

    console.log($(this).val());

}


function addOrder() {

    var anchor_id = $(this).children('div').find('.id').html();
    var anchor_name = $(this).children('div').find('.name').html();
    var anchor_price = $(this).children('div').find('.price').html();
    var anchor_number = $(this).children('div').find('.number').html();

    data = {
        'product_id':  anchor_id,
        'product_name': anchor_name,
        'product_price': anchor_price,
        'product_quantity': anchor_number
    };

    var rows = $('#orders tr');

    if( rows.length === 0 ) {

        populateTable();
        console.log('new item');

    } else {

        console.log('checking items');

        checkTableItems(rows, anchor_id);

    }
}
function checkTableItems(rows, id) {

    $.each(rows, function(key, value) {

        console.log(key + ' - ' + $(value).find('.productID').html());
        console.log(id + ' - ' + $(this).find('.productID').html());


        if( id === $(value).find('.productID').html()) {
            console.log('increase quantity if item match');
            $(value).find('input').val( +$(value).find('input').val()+1 );
            return false;
        } else {
            populateTable();
        }

    });

}

function populateTable() {

    var order_close = '<td><button href="#" class="btn default red-stripe"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></td>';
    var order_name = '<td class="productname"><div class="productID" style="display:none">'+data.product_id+'</div>'+data.product_name+'</td>';
    var order_price = '<td>'+data.product_price+'</td>';
    var order_quantity = '<td class="hidden-xs" ><div class="form-group"><div class="input-inline input-small"><input type="text" value="1" name="demo1" class="quantity form-control touchspin_demo1" ></div></div></td>';

    $('#orders').append('<tr>'+order_close+order_name+order_quantity+order_price+'<td class="total">1</td></tr>');

    ComponentsFormTools.init(); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong, because the bind event does not trigger when I change its value, and the checkTableItems only reads the first element in row.

PS. I think I have the wrong selector or wrong logic inside $.each loop...

EDIT: changed document ready, and placed inputTotal out of jQuery ready function, still no event triggered.

Comment: What is the expected result of `$.when( $.ready )`?

Comment: You can trigger the event manually by adding this line wherever needed **$(“.tile”).trigger(“click”)**

Comment: @maddy23285 That is not what I need to do. I can't trigger it manually, I need it to work when ever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after 24h I finally solved the issue, here is the working solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Document is ready.

    var data = {};

    console.log('log');

    $('.tile').bind('click', addOrder);

});

$(document).on('change', '.quantity', function() {

    console.log('quantity change event');

    // Input Total calc

});

function addOrder() {

    var anchor_id = $(this).children('div').find('.id > input').val();
    var anchor_name = $(this).children('div').find('.name').html();
    var anchor_price = $(this).children('div').find('.price').html();
    var anchor_number = $(this).children('div').find('.number').html();

    var data = {
        'product_id':  anchor_id,
        'product_name': anchor_name,
        'product_price': anchor_price,
        'product_quantity': anchor_number
    };

    var rows = $('#orders tr');

    var check = checkTableItems(data);

    if( !check ) {

        populateTable(data);

    } else {

        console.log('value increased!');

    }

}

function checkTableItems(data) {

    var b = false;
    var rows_count = $('#orders tr').length;

    console.log('row count: ' +rows_count);
    console.log('selected item id: ' +data.product_id);

    if ( rows_count == 0 ) {

        b = false;
        console.log('first item');

    } else {

        console.log('checkingTable');

        for( var i = 0; i <= rows_count; i++ ) {

            console.log('number of row ' + i);

            row_value = $('#orders > tr > td > input')[i];

            if( row_value == undefined ) {
                continue;
            }

            if( row_value.value == data.product_id ) {

                console.log('found item, increasing value');
                $('input[name="demo1"]')[i].value = +$('input[name="demo1"]')[i].value + 1;
                b = true;
            }

            if(b) {

                return true;
                break;

            }

        }

    }

    if(!b) {
        console.log('New item in table');
        return false;
    }

}



function populateTable(data) {

    var value = '<input value="'+data.product_id+'" />';

    var order_id = '<td style="display:none" class="productID">'+value+'</td>';
    var order_close = '<td><button href="#" class="btn default red-stripe"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></td>';
    var order_name = '<td class="productname">'+data.product_name+'</td>';
    var order_price = '<td>'+data.product_price+'</td>';
    var order_quantity = '<td class="hidden-xs" ><div class="form-group"><div class="input-inline input-small"><input type="text" value="1" name="demo1" class="quantity form-control touchspin_demo1" ></div></div></td>';

    $('#orders').append('<tr>'+order_id+order_close+order_name+order_quantity+order_price+'<td class="total">1</td></tr>');

    ComponentsFormTools.init(); 

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a reference to `$.ready` to `$.when()`.

`$.when( $.ready )` is not the same as `$(document).ready()` or `jQuery(function() {})`.

Also `inputTotal` is not defined.

Define `inputTotal` function and use `jQuery(function() {})` without `$.when()` as `.then()` is not expected to be chained to `jQuery(function() {})`.

Comment: I thought so, I'll give it a try :D Thanks

Comment: Sorry but there is no difference actually. The function is defined, but no event .

Comment: Where is the function defined at the code at the original Question?

Comment: At the bottom of html document, although the html structure does not matter, I can also make a fiddle but I'm working inside Laravel application

Comment: @TheBumpaster Cannot reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/ucxv55u4/. Should the selector `".quantitiy"` be `".quantity"`?

Comment: OMG, thank you. I feel so dumb right now haha :D Well that solves one issue, now I need to figure out this $.each loop

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ucxv55u4/3/ Take a look, try to click on the item name, you'll see that only the first item is being checked and value increased, all others are being just added...

Comment: @TheBumpaster Not certain what you are attempting to describe and how that is related to the original question? The `change` event is dispatched here. What are the exact steps that need to be taken to reproduce the issue that you are trying to describe? How you reduce the code to the minimal parts necessary to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Okay, I'll try to make it simple. When I click on the .tile, I need to check if that tile data is in table, if not, I should add it (appending it), if there is the same .tile inside table, then I should only increase the value of input field inside table.

Comment: @TheBumpaster Still not following what the issue is.

Comment: Try the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ucxv55u4/3/

Click on the Item 1 several times, and try to click on Item 2. 

You'll see that Item 1 is increasing its value on input, but Item 2 is being duplicated...

I need that to work on every Item, not just Item 1

Comment: The `.init()` call should be commented at jsfiddle. The result here is `Item 1 

4
11 1` at first line and `Item 2 

1
20 1` when clicking "Item 1" four times then clicking "Item 2" once. What is the expected result?

Comment: Item clicked [some number of times], should be in table and input should increase by [some number of times] for each row in table, not just the first one. My code does not work good, I'll figure this out...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163592/discussion-between-the-bumpaster-and-guest271314).